# How can i short the commands in tabular environment?

Tags: tables, macros, shortcut

Table is list as follows.

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Keys} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Type}
\end{tabular}
```

I want to somehow short the commands

```
**{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|}**
```

into some short command like `**\firststyle**`, so i do not need to copy long string all the time.

```
\begin{tabular} {\firststyle}
        \hline
        \textbf{Keys} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Type}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think `\newcolumntype` from `array` package is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\newcolumntype` from `array` package, you can define a new column type, with or without parameters. See Section 1.1 of the [package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{A}{|M{2cm}|M{7cm}|M{1cm}|}

\begin{document}
You can define a column type with a parameter:

\begin{tabular}{|M{2cm}|M{7cm}|M{1cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Keys} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Type}
\end{tabular}

You can even define a unique column type for all the columns of your table:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{A}{|M{2cm}|M{7cm}|M{1cm}|}

\begin{document}
You can define a column type with a parameter:

\begin{tabular}{|M{2cm}|M{7cm}|M{1cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Keys} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Type}
\end{tabular}

I don't know how much this is orthodox, but you can even define a unique column type for all the columns of your table:

\begin{tabular}{A}
        \hline
        \textbf{Keys} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Type}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks !!!! problem solved

Comment: @xiaojiuwo You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer!